# AdMob on myApp Android

Tags: android, admob

i have problem with my app Android 
i have webview, button, date, time, and admob .
But admob component is trasparent do not view it, and do not have error.
Please help me to resolve this problem

Why?

> XML File Code: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.magicone.ifa.IlFotografoAngelo"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow">

    <TextClock
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textColor="#007006"
        android:format24Hour="EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy "
        android:format12Hour="EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy " />

    <TextClock
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Time"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textColor="#007006"
        android:format24Hour="- HH:mm:ss"
        android:format12Hour="- HH:mm:ss" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/app"
        android:id="@+id/tV1"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

</TableRow>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

</WebView>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="65dp">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton"
        android:src="@drawable/wss_200"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/im"
        android:onClick="goweb"
        android:elevation="10dp" />

</TableRow>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_x="4dp"
    android:layout_y="179dp" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Java Code:

```
package com.magicone.ifa;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import android.os.Bundle;

// import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice.getDeviceId;

public class IlFotografoAngelo extends AppCompatActivity {
//    private ProgressBar progress;

    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override //crea l'attività
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_il_fotografo_angelo);

//banner admod
        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
//        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-5565937431369368~7774103043");
        // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
        // values/strings.xml.
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
           mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


//setta la prima view web al primo sito web
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.ilfotografoangelo.it/");
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


// Progress Bar Top
        final ProgressBar Pbar;
//        final TextView txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV1);
        Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb1);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
                if(progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
//                    txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                Pbar.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress == 100) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
//                    txtview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

}
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
  // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
            return true;
        }
  // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
  // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


//bottone con immagine cambia sito web
    public void goweb (View view) {
        final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.webshowstudio.it/");
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setInitialScale(1);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Transparent? probably isn´t being displayed correctly, Look into your LogCat!